# Событие изменения содержимого тега

Tags: javascript, html, dom, события

Есть ли событие в JavaScript, возникающее при изменении содержимого тега? Например, при изменении содержимого `<div></div>`

Comment: Любого тега или какого-то конкретного? Меняете содержимое вы или нет?

Comment: Прочитайте про `onchange`. Если скорректируете вопрос - сможем более точно направить вас.

Comment: Для блочного тега, типа <div></div>, изменяю не я. Просто с Greasemonkey балуюсь

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Прослушать можно любой тег. Для прослушки изменения в поддереве нужно использовать [DOMSubtreeModified](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php).

В примере ниже есть 2 параграфа `<p>` - `demo1` и `demo2`. На `document` установлено событие клика - такое, что при клике на любой участок страницы, содержимое `demo1` меняется на `demo1 -> Hello World!`. Другой слушатель ждёт изменение в поддереве `demo1`, и когда событие наступает, содержимое `demo2` меняется на `demo1 Changed!`

```js
document.getElementById("demo1").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "demo1 Changed!"
});

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "demo1 -> Hello World!";
});
```

```html
<p id="demo1">demo1</p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 21):

### Введение

---

Была попытка сделать события на изменения элементов в DOM, да всплыла, уж очень оно сильно влияло на производительность. Называются они в литературе [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events):

1. `DOMAttrModified` - если изменился атрибут у элемента DOM;
2. `DOMAttributeNameChanged` - если изменилось имя атрибута у элемента DOM;
3. `DOMCharacterDataModified` - если изменился какой-либо текст, будь то обычный 'text node' или простой комментарий у элемента DOM;
4. `DOMElementNameChanged` - если изменилось имя у элемента DOM;
5. `DOMNodeInserted` - если у элемента DOM произошла вставка нового элемента;
6. `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` - если произошла вставка нового элемента в `document`;
7. `DOMNodeRemoved` - если у элемента DOM произошло удаление какого-либо элемента;
8. `DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument` - если произошло удаление какого-либо элемента в `document`;
9. `DOMSubtreeModified` - если произошло какое-либо изменение в `document`.

Все они 'deprecated' и крайне не рекомендуются к использованию. Тем более, далеко не факт, что они будут работать в *Вашем* браузере, а проверить наличие этого события не такая уж тривиальная задача, так как атрибутов у элементов с одноименным названием нет.

### Альтернатива 0, для внимательных

---

Как альтернатива примем тот факт, что всегда можно создавать свои события, всплывающие при изменениях. То есть можно сделать вот так:

1. придумываем название события, например, `DOM:changed`;
2. создаем функции-обработчики и подписываем их на эти события;
3. находим все функции, которые могут потенциально изменить DOM;
4. при любых, интересующих Вас, изменениях в DOM в этих функциях вызываем пользовательское событие.

У этого метода потрясающие возможности в управлении уведомлениями, всегда можно выбрать, что вызывает событие, аккуратно их фильтровать и создавать удобную атмосферу для их вызова. Но всегда есть возможность забыть добавить это в код, надо быть *внимательным* и тщательно всё затестировать.

### Альтернатива 1, простая

---

Можно придумать ещё два способа это сделать.

Первый, в лоб, не совсем корректный, но имеет место жить на небольших данных, далее я расскажу о правильном:

1. берём эталонный `.innerHTML` у Вашего `div`'а и сохраняем его куда угодно, например, в `sessionStorage`
2. каждые n секунд сравниваем текущий `.innerHTML` с эталонным, если не равны, значит произошли какие-либо изменения и вызываем callback. Можно красиво обернуть в промис. Можно даже вместо вызова callback вызывать свое *пользовательское* событие.

Способ хорош, быстр, если `div` не многокилометровый. Самое главное - весьма и весьма кроссбраузерный, заработает даже в ie7. Но вот если `div` будет большим, то это может вызывать тормоза.

### Альтернатива 2, то, что надо

---

Второй способ правильный. После неудачной попытки со специальными событиями, придумали, оно действительно работает в хороших браузерах, [MutationObserver()](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutation%20Observer), а если нет, то его [полифилл](https://github.com/megawac/MutationObserver.js/tree/master). Как его использовать? А вот так.

Сначала создадим объект `MutationObserver`:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.dir(mutation); //объект с изменениями
    });    
});
```

В данном случае `mutations` - массив `MutationRecord`, каждый элемент которого содержит следующие поля:

1. `type` - все измененные атрибуты или `characterData` (текстовый элемент или комментарий) или `childList` в зависимости от типа мутации;
2. `target` - элемент дерева, в котором произошло изменение;
3. `addedNodes` - `NodeList`, содержащий добавленные элементы дерева, логично, что он будет пуст (`*.length == 0`), если таких не будет.
4. `removedNodes` - `NodeList`, содержащий удаленные элементы дерева, он тоже будет пуст, если таких иметься не будет;
5. `previousSibling` - предыдущий сосед по дереву добавленного или удаленного элемента или `null`;
6. `nextSibling` - следующий сосед по дереву добавленного или удаленного элемента или `null`;
7. `attributeName` - имя измененного атрибута или `null`;
8. `oldValue` - старые значения, до изменения, но в случае, если изменение произошло в `childList` - `null`.

Затем, чтобы эта прелесть заработала, скажем интерпретатору "начать слежение":

```
observer.observe(
    elem,
    {
        childList: true,
        attributes: true,
        subtree: true,
        characterData: true,
        attributeOldValue: true,
        characterDataOldValue: true,
        attributeFilter: true
    }
);
```

Первым аргументом мы передаем объект DOM, за которым нужно следить, вторым - то, как мы будем следить:

1. `childList` - следим за вставкой/удалением элементов в `childList`;
2. `attributes` - следим за изменением атрибутов
3. `characterData` - следим за изменением `characterData` (текстовые элементы или комментарии)
4. `attributeOldValue` - запоминаем значение атрибута до изменения
5. `characterDataOldValue` - запоминаем значение `characterData` до изменения
6. `attributeFilter` - `Array` тех атрибутов, за которыми будем следить

Для того, чтобы остановить слежение можно вызвать метод `observer.disconnect();`.

### Предостережение

---

Не советую изменять элемент DOM, за которым мы следим, может получиться весьма пикантная ситуация.

### Забытая на потом последняя альтернатива

---

Стоит упомянуть, что существует стандартное событие, полностью кроссбраузерное и работающее - `onchange`.

Работает оно в элементах `<input>`, `<select>`, и `<textarea>`. Срабатывает при *изменении*, увы *только пользователем*, данных внутри *только этих* объектов. При изменении данных в скрипте, событие надо вызывать собственноручно.

Comment: Я бы добавил еще вариант с использованием собственных событий. При загрузке документа мы подписываемся на собственное событие, а после необходимых изменений содержимого вручную объявляем о нем.

Comment: @VenZell, по сути это Альтернатива 1 в моем ответе, только вызов коллбека можно заменить созданием пользовательского события. Или я Вас не правильно понял? Добавлю это в ответ.

Comment: Сделал пример: https://jsfiddle.net/0ud89twf/ чтобы лучше пояснить свою мысль.

Comment: @VenZell, можно и так, но тогда надо в любую функцию изменяющую дом добавлять, но правда, имеет право существовать как вариант. Спасибо.