# Событие изменения DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Все привет!
У меня есть поле ввода для поиска, и блок li элементов под ним для показа автодолнений к введенному тексту(как в google поиске).
Проблема в том что у меня не получается перехватить событие изменений этих li элементов.
Пробовал использовать jquery события change и DOMSubtreeModified но они почему то не работают.
Я могу конечно сохранять старое состояние и сравнивать его с новым после событие change в поле ввода, но не хочется писать лишний код особенно если есть простое решение.

Comment: требуется что-то посложнее)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: @Jean-Claude Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: вообще для каждого из них требуется свое отслеживание, для инпута например keyup, для списка click, не проще ли пойти этим путем, нежели как по ссылке выше?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я до сих пор сопротивляюсь тому, что разработчик обязан знать инглиш, но минимальный набор слов все же необходим... мне перевести тот ответ? да щас))))

Comment: @Jean-Claude Идея не столько в английском, сколько в том, что ссылки имеют свойство становится нерабочими. Публикую минимальный пример решения мы гарантируем, что запись в базе знаний будет содержать ответ вне зависимости от работоспособности ссылки, то есть будет «полноценной».

Comment: Как-то я отвечал на похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462701/Событие-изменения-содержимого-тега/462725