Можно ли скрыть блок по условию в JavaScript
Есть 3 блока. Блок warning1 иногда скрывается сос страницы. Возможно ли используя JavaScript скрыть блок warning3 если не отображается warning1?


<div class="warning1" title = "Леопард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning3">
  <p>Beware of the leopards</p>
</div>




Можно. Что бы это сделать, надо понимать, по каким условиям и как( скрывается первый блок, тогда можно придумать, как отслеживать данное событие и скрывать третий.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462701/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0

А если поставить просто проверку на то что отображается первый блок или нет? Как css например

Beware of the leopard 1


Beware of the leopard 2


Beware of the leopard 4


Beware of the leopard 3

.warning3{
display: none;
background: #fcc;
}
.warning3[title="Леопард"] ~ .warning3 {
display: flex;
}

С помощью JS


const divWarning1 = document.querySelector(`div.warning1`);
const divWarning3 = document.querySelector(`div.warning3`);
const inputToggle = document.querySelector(`input#toggle`);
inputToggle.addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
  divWarning1.hidden = !divWarning1.hidden;
  divWarning3.hidden = divWarning1.hidden; // warning3 скрывается если скрыта warning1
});
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">Click it</label>
<div class="warning1" title="Леопард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning3">
  <p>Beware of the leopards</p>
</div>



Ещё с помошью JS


const divWarning1 = document.querySelector(`div.warning1`);
const divWarning3 = document.querySelector(`div.warning3`);
const inputToggle = document.querySelector(`input#toggle`);
inputToggle.addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
  divWarning1.hidden = !divWarning1.hidden;
});
new MutationObserver(() => {
  divWarning3.hidden = divWarning1.hidden;
}).observe(divWarning1, { attributes: true, attributeFilter: [`hidden`] });
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">Click it</label>
<div class="warning1" title="Леопард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning3">
  <p>Beware of the leopards</p>
</div>



Даже без JS
Часть с JS нужно только для демонстрации


const divWarning1 = document.querySelector(`div.warning1`);
const inputToggle = document.querySelector(`input#toggle`);
inputToggle.addEventListener(`change`, (event) => {
  divWarning1.hidden = !divWarning1.hidden;
});
div.warning1[hidden]~div.warning3 {
  display: none;
}
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">Click it</label>
<div class="warning1" title="Леопард">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning2">
  <p>Beware of the leopard</p>
</div>
<div class="warning3">
  <p>Beware of the leopards</p>
</div>




А без кнопки просто при загрузки страницы проверять есть ли warning1 на странице или нет? и тогда убирать warning3

@Никита я ж написал, кнопка только для демонстрации. Чтобы вы смогли скрыть элемент и посмотреть что пример работает.

Да я понял, просто я прописал вместо  того что бы скрывать через кнопку
div.warning1 {
display: none;
}
но warning3 на месте

@Никита, потому что проверка основана на атрибуте hidden. Если будете скрывать через display: none; то надо будет проверить через getComputedStyle(divWarning1).display === "none";

Теперь разобрался. Спасибо
