Как получить текст у тега?
У меня есть данный код.


const el = document.getElementById("wrap-text");

console.log(el.textContent)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap-text">
      Some text
      <span>Some text 2</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



И в консоли выводиться данное сообщение:

Some text Some text 2

Но "Some text 2" не является текстом div элемента.
Также происходит и с innerText.
Как тогда получить текст внутри элементов без текстов других тегов?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Похоже, только собирать вручную из дочерних текстовых узлов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61299219

@Dev18, как эта ссылка связана с вопросом?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462725/264178 полезная ссылка, дубликат искала, вышел этот вопрос. Здесь нет ответа на ваш вопрос, но есть информация о MutationObserver, которая может быть полезна для отслеживания изменений в DOM в более широком контексте работы с элементами

@Dev18 Всё равно нет связи :) У автора ничего не меняется

Отдельной функции нет. Можно только пройтись по дочерним узлам и получить текст только текстовых узлов.
Для проверки, что узел текстовый можно проверить nodeType на значение Node.TEXT_NODE


const el = document.getElementById("wrap-text");

function onlyText(el) {
  var res = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var childNode = el.childNodes[i];
    if (childNode.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      res += childNode.textContent;
    }
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(onlyText(el))
<div id="wrap-text">
  Some text
  <span>Some text 2</span>
</div>



Пример с итераторами:


var onlyText = document.getElementById("wrap-text")
  .childNodes
  .values()
  .filter(n => n.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
  .map(n => n.textContent)
  .toArray()
  .join('');

console.log(onlyText)
<div id="wrap-text">
  Some text
  <span>Some text 2</span>
</div>




Спасибо большое за ответ!

[...document.getElementById("wrap-text").childNodes].filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).map(n => n.textContent.trim()).join(' ')

@АлександрИлларионов лучшее спасибо - это принять ответ. Для этого нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него.

@aepot Уж слишком много циклов для такой задачи :) И как по мне trim() тут скорее всего будет мешать, лучше оставить ноды как есть

@EzioMercer где циклы, которых много?

@aepot spread, filter, map и join. И trim вроде как тоже исползует цикл

@EzioMercer итератор же, который возвращается массивом. Цикл там по сути один, внутри join.

@aepot, нет, в js по умолчанию - это не итераторы - они сразу выполняются

@EzioMercer, trim может помочь в местах когда текстовый узел содержит пробельные символы, которые схлопываются браузером при выводе

@Grundy прости сенсей, я попутал.

@EzioMercer, добавил пример где filter и map - итераторы

На счёт trim я сказал, что он скорее всего будет мешать, потому что когда я игрался с твоим кодом, то тексты писались слитно, если использовать trim, что как по мне может быть неожиданностью

@EzioMercer. тексты писались слитно, если использовать trim - самое интересное - что это еще и от браузера может зависеть, как именно он разобьет текст на узлы

Серьёзно? Разве дерево не одинаково везде строится?) Есть какие-то примеры? Я щас быстренько глянул в Chrome и Firefox, работают одинаково

@EzioMercer, да, не всегда текстовые ноды нормализируются и объединяются, замечал когда пример с подсветкой делал

Спасибо, теперь буду знать :) (Надеюсь никогда не столкнусь с такой проблемой)

@EzioMercer, она довольна специфичная, поэтому вряд ли можно столкнуться при обычной работе :)
